# Compare current to previous when mapping array of objects onto html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I want to map an array of persons onto React components of the type person and want to also add a different field based on the previous object's values, usually you could do this if not comparing the values of current and previous object:

```
const PersonsMonth = ({persons}) => {
    const personsList = persons.map((person)=> <Person key={person.Id} person={person}/>)
    return(<>
     <h3>Group members</h3> 
     {personsList}
     </> 
   )
}
```

But what do I do if I want to say add a div when current person's height value is lower or higher than previous person's  height. For example this pseudocode

```
if(currentperson.height>formerperson.height)
<div className="taller">!</div> in front of <Person key={person.Id} person={person}/>
if(currentperson.height<formerperson.height)
<div className="shorter">!</div> in front of <Person key={person.Id} person={person}/>
```

Comment: When you say previous person do you mean to say the previous person in the array being mapped? Or the same person from the previous render cycle?

Comment: Previous person in the array being mapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the additional arguments passed to the map callback, the index and array being iterated over, to access the previous element in the array. Use the Optional Chaining operator (`?.`) to handle the edge case of mapping the first person in the array since they'll have no previous person before them in the array.

```
const PersonsMonth = ({ persons }) => {
  const personsList = persons.map((person, index, arr)=> {
    const prevPerson = arr[index - 1];

    if (prevPerson?.height && person.height > prevPerson.height) {
      return (
        <Fragment key={person.id}>
          <div className="taller">!</div> in front of <Person person={person}/>
        </Fragment>
      );
    } else if (prevPerson?.height && person.height > prevPerson.height) {
      return (
        <Fragment key={person.id}>
          <div className="shorter">!</div> in front of <Person person={person}/>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Person key={person.Id} person={person}/>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Group members</h3> 
      {personsList}
    </> 
  );
}
```

This could probably be made to be a little bit tighter code, more DRY.

```
const PersonsMonth = ({ persons }) => {
  const personsList = persons.map((person, index, arr)=> {
    const prevPerson = arr[index - 1];

    return (
      <Fragment key={person.id}>
        {prevPerson?.height && person.height !== prevPerson.height && (
          <>
            <div className={person.height > prevPerson?.height ? "taller" : "shorter">!</div> in front of 
          </>
        )}
        <Person person={person}/>
      </Fragment>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Group members</h3> 
      {personsList}
    </> 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sort persons before map in react component

```javascript
const persons = [
        {
            id:0,
            name:'user1',
            height:175,
        },
        {
            id:1,
            name:'user2',
            height:183,
        },
        {
            id:2,
            name:'user3',
            height:168,
        }
    ]
    const sortPersons = (persons) => {
        function compare( a, b ) {
            if ( a.height < b.height ){
                return -1;
            }
            if ( a.height > b.height ){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        return persons.sort( compare );
    }
    const PersonsMonth = () => {
        const personsList = sortPersons(persons).map((person)=> <p key={person.id} >{person.height}</p>)
        return(
            <>
                <h3>Group members</h3>
                {personsList}
            </>
        )
    }
```